# What is the 'color_mapping' attribute?

Tags: python, scripting

For procedural texture nodes, e.g., noise textures, voronoi textures, there's an attribute called 'color_mapping' that returns a ColorMapping object, with brightness, contrast, etc., attributes. They don't seem to be adjusted via the interface, so what are they?